# How to have a constant starting point for all threads java

Tags: java, multithreading

If I am running 2 threads in java, and both these threads call a function, is an instance of each function created per thread? or can one thread interfere with the updates of the other thread?
for instance, say I have a function as such:

```
void test () {
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
        S.o.p(i);
    }
}
```

If both threads call this function at the same time and thread1 has started the loop, and `i=2` when thread2 comes in, would thread2 start at 2, or would it start from 0?

Answer (score 1):

Local variables (for instance `int i`) are held only by the thread calling the function (each thread has its own stack and therefore locals will not be accessed by other threads). Memory not on the stack, such as static members, and non-static class members called by two threads) are accessible and modifiable by different threads.

To answer the question directly, both threads will operate independently (assuming `S.o.p` doesn't modify anything) as if the other thread were not running. If `S.o.p` Modifies some (e.g. static) value then both threads will modify it. Regardless, both thread will run in your `for` loop 20 times.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, threads only share what's called **'shared mutable state'**. Shared mutable state refers to instance variables in the class. For example, in the class below:

```
class account{

private int balance =0;

void test () {
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
        i++;
    }
}

}
```

All threads that access the test method are entirely independent of each other because methods and variables in methods (local variables) are executed on a per thread basis.

However, if you were to mutate the this.balance variable in the test method you would be sharing state of that variable among threads. To do so safely, wherever you touch the this.balance variable you must **synchronize** the method for thread safety or use a synchronized block. But it's far better to use  use atomic variables to avoid synchronization altogether.

That said, if S.o.p(...) is modifying shared mutable state then you need to use synchronized in the method signature or use a synchronized block.

Comment: You don't mutate it at all. You should create immutable variables if you want to publish and share them freely without synchronization. Create a new object instead and set the immutable in the constructor and only there without unsafe publication.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables of methods are not thread contentious so another thread will also start from i=0.

> Only class level instances and variables define the state of an
>   object, so those are considered as thread contentious.

Local variables are stored in each thread's own stack. That means that local variables are never shared between threads

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have the instance with method `test` with the *local* variable `i`. Local variables will be in stack **per thread** which means that all threads have own local variables. Note that you should synchronize access when you try to use data in heap (like fields of the instance) in multithreading environment. More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/